# zabbix - how to calculate average trigger

Tags: zabbix

Im using zabbix 5 and i dont understand how to create an avg trigger that will tell me if X item average has changed from the last week.

X item is returning a number, i want to know if there was a change from a week average comparing to the next week or day.

**For example :**

**case1:**  if last week avg was the number 7 and this week avg (was 8 or greater ) has gotten bigger + 1 even - i want a trigger

**case2:** if last week avg was the number 7 and 1 day avg (was 8 or greater) has exceeded this week avg +1 bigger - i want a trigger

I have this now :

```
{Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}].avg(7d)}=0
```

Should make it like?

```
{Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}].avg(7d)} < {Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}].avg(1h)}
```

or

```
{Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}].avg(14d)} < {Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}].avg(7d)}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/triggers/functions):

> avg (sec|#num,<time_shift>)
>
> sec or #num - maximum evaluation period1 in seconds or in latest
> collected values (preceded by a hash mark)
>
> time_shift (optional) -
> evaluation point is moved the number of seconds back in time
>
> Examples:
>
> ⇒ avg(#5) → average value for the five latest values
>
> ⇒ avg(1h) → average value for an hour
>
> ⇒ avg(1h,1d) → average value for an hour one day ago.

So:

- `{Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}].avg(7d)}` will return the average from TODAY-7 to TODAY
- `{Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}].avg(7d,7d)}` should return the average from TODAY-14 to TODAY-7

You can use these in your expression, or if you want you can create two calculated items and trigger on them: you will be able to use `change` and `abschange` functions as well.

The calculated item should be

- `avg(Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}],7d)`
- `avg(Template Ansible-Features:c.conn[{#CCC}],7d,7d)`